# Paint numbers from 1 to 8 with two colours

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint every number from 1 to 8 with two colours, such that there are no distinct numbers $a, b, c$ of the same colour with $a+b=c$? For example, you cannot have 2, 3 and 5 of the same colour since $2+3=5$.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this

> Red - $\{1,2,4,8\}$
>  Blue - $\{3,5,6,7\}$

Comment: Correct! Well done.