# Paint numbers from 1 to 23 with three colours

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint every number from 1 to 23 with three colours, such that there are no distinct numbers $,,$ of the same colour with $+=$? For example, you cannot have 2, 3 and 5 of the same colour since 2+3=5. You may need to use a computer to solve this.

Here is a similar puzzle for numbers 1 to 8 painted with two colours: [Paint numbers from 1 to 8 with two colours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90381/paint-numbers-from-1-to-8-with-two-colours)

Good luck!

Comment: This is a job for... S̶u̶p̶e̶r̶m̶a̶n̶ SAT solvers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that solution (thanks Python !) :

> Red : 1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 16, 22
>  Green : 3, 5, 6, 7, 19, 21, 23
>  Blue : 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20

Here is my code if you're curious !

> ```
>  # Tells for each color if it is available for this number
>  def getColorsAvailabilities(n):
>      av = [True] * 3
>      for i in range(1, (n+1) // 2): # Only iterate up to half the number
>          if (colors[i] == colors[n-i]):
>              # If i and (n-i) have same color, n cannot be of that color
>              av[colors[i]] = False
>      return av
>  
>  # Main recursive function
>  def test(n):
>      if (n >= 24):
>          return True
>      colorsAvailabilities = getColorsAvailabilities(n)
>      # Try each available color, in order
>      for color in range(3):
>          if colorsAvailabilities[color]:
>              colors[n] = color
>              if test(n+1):
>                  return True  # Stop when we found a solution
>      # If every available color results in a failure, backtrack
>      return False
>  
>  # First try : 1 and 2 have same colors
>  colors = [-1] * 24
>  colors[1] = 0
>  colors[2] = 0
>  print(test(3)) # It works !
>  print(colors) # My solution (with Red = 0, Green = 1, Blue = 2)
>  # Second try : 1 and 2 have different colors
>  colors = [-1] * 24
>  colors[1] = 0
>  colors[2] = 1
>  print(test(3)) # Doesn't work (stops at 22)
>  print(colors)
> ```

Comment: I saw someone else answer in the while I was editing my own answer, but since I have added my code, it is not a total duplicate, so here you go ^^

Answer (score 9):

I used a computer, and found the following solution:

> First group: $1,2,4,8,11,22$
>  Second group: $3,5,6,7,19,21,23$
>  Third group: $9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20$

You can move $16$ or $17$ to the first group, but not both. Those are the only three solutions according to my program, other than permuting the groups. Note that $24$ cannot be added to any group.